# Response.BinaryWrite() causing file corruption

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, httpresponse, binarywriter

When writing a file to the `HttpResponse` the file is being corrupted.
The file(s) I'm writing are saved to disc prior to writing. I've tested that the generated/saved file is fine, it's only when writing to the response.
I've tested using multiple file types (`text` and `excel`) and receive the same issue.
When using excel (`openXML`), the file opens once Excel repairs it.
the error in the file when viewing the contents via notepad is:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.    at
>   System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()    at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()    at
>   SPAM.WEB.Reports.Wrapper.LaunchQuarterlyReportDownload() in C:\Use......

The code i'm using to write the file is:

```
string fileDownloadPath = GetConfigValue("FileUploadPath");
string filePath = fileDownloadPath + BUSINESS.Business.QuarterlyAuditReport.getRecentQuarter() + ".xlsx";
BUSINESS.Business.QuarterlyAuditReport.GetSpreadSheet(filePath);
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open).CopyTo(memStream);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.GetBuffer());            
memStream.Dispose();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: I suggest that you use a text file and then do a binary compare of the file from the server to the file that is saved on the client to see what the difference is.  That will get us a better idea of what is corrupted in the file.

Comment: GetBuffer() gets the whole buffer not the valid contents within the buffer so it will contain trailing garbage.  ToArray() is one way around this or simply BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(...))

Comment: @Mike when using a text file (test.txt) and having "testing" as the content, the file becomes corrupted
  System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()

Comment: Is this Web Forms? Web API? MVC?

Comment: It's a Web Forms project

Comment: I think Alex is probably on to something with his comment.  The exceptions are probably coming from the Response.End() call.  If I remember right this is implemented by throwing a ThreadAbort exception.

Comment: @Mike, i've tried the ToArray() and File.ReadAll..... and still receive the same error in the output

Comment: resolved: there was some upper level error handling (bad error handling) that was writing the error to the response (Response.Write(ex.ToString());. this caused the file to contain the stack trace from the exception.